# How does Git tracks info of file changes on top of OS?

Tags: git, checksum

[Git document](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F) says :

> Everything in Git is checksummed before it is stored and is then
> referred to by that checksum. This means it’s impossible to change the
> contents of any file or directory without Git knowing about it.

In my understanding above can only be done by introducing one more step between user and OS  to save the file i.e before a file in the Git repository is saved first it's checksum is created and saved as tracking info by Git and then only save operation control is given back to OS and file is saved. I searched but didn't find any paragraph on this behind the scence activity. Any description, pointer, link ?

Comment: git doesn't react to filesystem events, it computes the required in formation when you run a git command (`git status`, `git diff`, ...). The only optimization is: it does rely on the filesystem's modification date to avoid recomputing the hash of every file.

Comment: No, you've got how things work all jumbled up. Files can be (re)named at any time, whether Git figures out the hash of the added content before or after or while writing the file is immaterial.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about "how git internally works?"

To answer your question in a black box, I would go in 2 steps:

1. When you `git init` it creates a folder named as *.git*.
2. This folder tracks all the files and folders inside that directory except those you explicitly ignored - those files are saved into the .gitignore file.

Whenever you are doing any changes to the files, those changes are directly made to the working directory. The OS doesn't know anything about the git system or if there exists any.

And the git cleverly maintains the Blob Structure, so it checks the latest changes you are about to commit with the existing changes, and checks the difference between the previous and current working directory.

You could find more indepth lecture about the internals [here](https://youtu.be/52MFjdGH20o).